# How do I delete the target of a symbolic link without deleting the link itself?

Tags: command-line, delete, symbolic-link

I have a symbolic link `~/Desktop/test.txt` which points to `~/rendu/test.txt`.

I know ONLY the path of `~/Desktop/test.txt`, I want a fast way to delete `~/rendu/test.txt` WITHOUT deleting the symbolic link.

For the one who want to know why: I have a file named `crypted.xxx` on my desktop, which is encrypted and contains my password.

When I want to update my encrypted file, I decrypt it and it create `crypted.txt` in a special directory. So I make a link to that file on my desktop for practical reasons. But after looking at my `crypted.txt`, I want to quickly delete this `crypted.txt` (but not the link in the desktop).

Comment: wait, you want to *delete* the file (as your question suggests) or *delete the content* of the file (as the title sais)

Comment: Delete the file and keep the symbolic link, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Maybe you could consider using a dedicated password manager instead? [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) is pretty good, for example, and is in the repos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

using `find` to find the symlink and then using `readlink` to get the full path to the target to `rm`:

```
find ~/Desktop/ -type l -name 'test.txt' -exec bash -c 'rm "$(readlink -f "$1")"' _ {} \;
```

Or as you know the link name already:

```
rm "$(readlink -f ~/Desktop/test.txt)"
```

Comment: Be careful with relative links though. A relative symbolic link is interpreted as relative to the directory it is located in. But your `rm` command will interpret it as relative to the current directory of the shell. Hence there is a possibility for that command to delete a different file from what the symbolic link was pointing to.

Comment: @kasperd With `-f` `-e` or `-m` the full path is returned, even if the target symlink points to a relative path, so yes, that 's a concern in case of `rm "$(readlink ~/Desktop/test.txt)"`, but not when using `-f` `-e` or `-m`.

Comment: @kos You are right. In that case you only have to worry if there could be any race conditions.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use [realpath](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/realpath.1.html), which does in this case the same thing as `readlink -f` (but also works if the target itself is not a link).

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

```
printf "" > "$(readlink '/path/to/link')"
```

to *clear* the file, or

```
rm "$(readlink '/path/to/link')"
```

to *remove* the file.